# HTML: How do I actually write text in a second column?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a website menu catalog for my restaurant and I am stuck on how to write text in the second column. See picture below. It is a drop down menu with two columns.[image]

Also when I am using three columns it looks like this.[image]

How do I fix it so the text are in the first column and they have the same formatting as the first picture? Here is my code,

```css
body {
  background: #db2811;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 2em 4em;
  max-width: 65%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0)
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff200;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.nav ul {
  *zoom: 1;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-left: -3%;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav ul:before,
.nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
.nav ul > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #595959;
  font-size: 16px
}
.nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #595959;
}
.nav li ul {
  background: #273754;
}
.nav li ul li {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid lightblue;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-rule: 1px solid lightblue;
  /* Firefox */
  column-rule: 1px solid lightblue;
  width: 500px;
}
.nav li ul a {
  border: none;
}
.nav li ul a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.nav li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 36px;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(400) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition: 350ms;
  -moz-transition: 350ms;
  -o-transition: 350ms;
  transition: 350ms;
}
.nav ul > li:hover ul {
  max-height: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(400) rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<h1>Menu</h1>
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Drinks</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Pepsi</a></li>
        <li><a>Diet Pepsi</a></li>
        <li><a>Mountain Dew</a></li>
        <li><a>Lemonade</a></li>
        <li><a>Sierra Mist</a></li>
        <li><a>Dr. Pepper</a></li>
        <li>
          <a></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I think you wanted the inner ul to have three columns, not the list items in them.

Comment: Hmm i just tried that and it seems to be bringing me closer to the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `inline-block` display for you `li` elements and make their width to 50%. then the `ul` `width`to 100%